# Angular2 how can i get checkbox value

Tags: angular2-forms

Here i'm new to ang2 please help

```
    <input type="checkbox" value="chk1" (change)="mon($event)" />

  mon(eve: any) {
        console.log(eve);
        alert(eve);
    }
```

Here how can i get checkbox value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
mon(eve: any) {
  console.log(eve.target.checked);
  alert(eve.target.checked);
}
```

`eve.target.checked` should be boolean `true` if checked and `false` otherwise.

If you need to get the value, which is always 'chk1' in your case, get it at `eve.target.value`